# Instanting a dynamic class with a namespace from a different class

Tags: php

One of the functions I have in my App.php class which is located in the App folder in the root directory. The function needs to instantiate a controller class which is located inside the App/Controllers folder with a different namespace obviously.

I'm getting the following error when calling a new class by the controller name:
I don't understand why it's looking for the class PagesController.php inside the App.php class.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PagesController.php' not found in D:\wamp64\www\app\App.php on line 36

```
public function renderPage($page, $route) {
    $this->page = $page;
    if(file_exists(CONTROLLERS . '/' . $route['controller'] . '.php')) {
        $controllerFile = $route['controller'] . '.php';
        $controller = new $controllerFile();
        echo 'YES CONTROLLER!';
    } else {
        echo 'no :<';
    }
    echo $this->plates->render("pages::$page");
}
```

Comment: You need `classname`, not a `filename` for `new` operator

Comment: And what namespace should be used? Where's `require` or `include` of a file?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you check if file exists, but never include that file to later use it's file.

Later you have controller file name `$route['controller'] . '.php'` and try to call it as `new $route['controller'] . '.php';` - here is error.

You need to include it:

```
$controllerFile = CONTROLLERS . '/' . $route['controller'] . '.php';

if(file_exists($controllerFile)) {
    require_once($controllerFile);
    $controller = new $route['controller']();
    echo 'YES CONTROLLER!';
}
```

---

> I don't understand why it's looking for the class PagesController.php inside the App.php class

Because `$route['controller']` contains `PageController` string.

Comment: Still getting the error: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PagesController' not found in D:\wamp64\www\app\App.php on line 39........... The PagesController class is in the D:\wamp64\www\app\controllers folder so I don't know why it's looking in the App.php file itself. Maybe because of the name space?

Comment: @PaulDiamant It's not looking *inside class*, just tells you where is your error. Tell me what `CONTROLLERS . '/' . $route['controller'] . '.php'` output is. Also make sure that in this file there is class PageController and it's not under namespace.

Comment: It works now after I removed my namespace from PagesController... however I want to use the name space, is there a way to add namespace app\controllers to the dynamic invoke method?

Comment: @Paul If you want to instantiate a class which is in a namespace, then you need to use the *fully qualified name*, i.e. `$c = 'Foo\Bar\Baz'; new $c()`.

Comment: @Deceze Yeah, thank you, i've realized it myself a couple minutes ago!

Answer (score 0):

I've come with a solution finally;

You have to append the namespace using the \ slash and by escaping it. So now it works with using a namespace.

```
public function renderPage($page, $route) {
        $this->page = $page;
        $controllerFile = CONTROLLERS . '/' . $route['controller'] . '.php';
        if(file_exists($controllerFile)) {
            require (CONTROLLERS . '/' . $route['controller'] . '.php');
            $class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\controllers\\' . $route['controller'];
            $controller = new $class();
        }

        echo $this->plates->render("pages::$page");
    }
```